# Why isn't grep -E regex removing the outer tags when I ask it to?

Tags: regex, grep

If I have a file with `<html>` tags all over the place, and it will be structured nicely, and I use a regex like

```
grep -E '<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>'
```

to try to pull out the text inside the `<p>` tag, it doesn't work. I do get the content, but it also include the tags. Why is grep regex broken?

The type of stuff I'm talking about is;

```
<html>
<body> 
<p>This is text I want</p>
```

It'll produce `<p>This is text I want</p>` but not `This is text I want`. I've told it in `<\s*p[^>]*>` That I specifically don't want that included in the group, but it includes it anyway. What gives?

EDIT: I realize now that I need to include the usage, please excuse my ignorance, I'm working on it. I'm not using a static file. It's a grab using `wget "http://example.com/page/$i" -O - | grep -E '<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>' | cut -d\" -f2 | while read id` etc... It's supposed to be taking a page and pulling the paragraph info out and creating a filename based on that paragraph.

Comment: grep returns the entire line that contains the match.  You need a different tool.  You could use sed, awk, or many other things but regex isn't designed for parsing HTML.  You should try something designed for parsing HTML.  .NET regex can do nested tags so that flavor of regex might be ok.

Comment: The output is used as a filename, directly from -O in wget. I'm not looking for any additional flexibility, just to get that text in the tag from that exact scenario. Is there really no way to just keep using grep?

Comment: I don't care what tool it is as long as I can grab the info in between a paragraph tag and use it with wget in place of the grep.

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Po '(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)' file.html`

Comment: Cyrus, you are the best. That worked like a charm. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Instead of added "solved" to the title, post your answer and mark it. Also upvote answers when useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just using the wrong tool. grep is to do `g/re/p`, it's not an editor so you shouldn't expect to be able to use it to modify the text that matches the regexp. To edit text you need `sed` or similar, e.g. with your original regexp:

```
$ sed -E -n 's:<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>:\1:p' file
This is text I want
```

P.S. I see someone suggested `grep -P` - just be aware that according to the man page that is "highly experimental" and it has been removed from some greps and has been reported as causing core dumps so YMMV.